# Convergence of fourier series and Parseval's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

On Rudin page 187, we have $f(x) \sim \sum_1^{\infty} c_n\phi_n(x)$. And right next to it, it wrote "Note that the symbol $\sim$ implies nothing about the convergence of the series; it merely says that the coefficients are given by $c_n=\int_a^b f(t)\overline{\phi_n(t)}dt$.

After reading that, I kept in mind that the Fourier series of a function may not converge. And later in theorem 8.14-15, some convergence of Fourier series was discussed.

Then when I read about Parseval's theorem, I got confused, because it wrote $f(x)\sim \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}$ (and I still kept in mind that $\sim$ doesn't imply convergence), and the theorem implies that $\|f-s_N(f;x)\|\to 0$, i.e. $\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N(f;x) = f$. To me it seems like the Fourier series $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}$ of $f$ does converge to $f$? But I thought it is not always the case that the Fourier series of a function converges to function itself (and he mentioned that $\sim$ does not mean convergence).

I think I misunderstood something important. Or does Parseval's theorem say that for every Riemann-integrable (or Lebesgue-integrable) function $f$, its Fourier series does not necessarily converge to itself, but if we in the context of $L^2$ metric space, then its Fourier series will always converge to itself?

Answer (score 2):

The Fourier series of any $L^{2}$ function converges to the function in $L^{2}$ norm, but the series may not converge at every point. There are may types of convergence for series of functions and you have to  distinguish between different types of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier series of an $L^2$ function converges pointwise almost everywhere to the original function. That's a very difficult-to-prove 1966 result due to Lennart Carleson. It is not so difficult to prove that the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function converges in $L^2$, which automatically gives the existence of a subsequence that converges pointwise almost everywhere.